# FLORIS - changing wind speed/direction

Tags: floris

I have a question about generalizing the FLORIS model across wind speeds/directions and turbine type:

Typically when analyzing wake effects in a wind farm simulations are run across a reasonable observed wind spectrum (i.e. 0 m/s to 30 m/s) and across the entire wind rose (i.e. 0 deg to 360 degrees). Many of the examples provided (i.e. `example_0030_demo_energy_ratio.py`) show iteration through variable wind speed and wind direction in order to capture varying wake effects under these conditions. However many of the other variables used in the wake simulation depend on wind speed and direction. For example tip speed ratio, turbulence intensity, axial induction factor. These variables are not updated throughout the wind speed/direction simulations?

My question is what are best practices for running FLORIS across a range of wind speed and directions? Should all dependent variables be updated with each run and the example leaves this out to simplify?

Similarly, many of the turbine/wake model variables are difficult to track down/compute across turbine types i.e. `pP`, `pT`, `mE`, `ka` etc. Do you have any guidelines on these variables? In particular, for the wake constants are the defaults values in the `example_input.json` file broadly applicable across wind turbine types? Is the expectation that these variables are determined experimentally.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because *what are best practices for running FLORIS across a range of wind speed and directions?* is not a matter of programming.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Can you recommend a better forum for asking questions about the FLORIS package related to theory, variable definitions, and best practices?

Comment: Perhaps here https://wind.nrel.gov/forum/wind/viewforum.php?f=42